# How to get the no of same boolean occur in two list in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have dataframe having

```
    A    B   C     D
0  True  5  True  True
1  True  6  False False
2  False 5  True  True
3  False 8  True  False
4  True  2  True  True
```

It should print the count when Column D is True, how many times Column A and Column C are True.

**Expected Output**

A : 2
C : 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by column `D` because boolean in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for also filter by columns names and last for count `True`s values is used `sum`:

```
s = df.loc[df.D, ['A','C']].sum()
print (s)
A    2
C    3
dtype: int64
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.loc[df.D, ['A','C']])
       A     C
0   True  True
2  False  True
4   True  True
```